# Retrieve android.os.Build.... system properties via purely native Android app

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have a purely native Android NDK app, and need to retrieve values such as:
android.os.Build.MODEL

Unfortunately I cannot find good examples of how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NDK isn't meant to replace the Java based API but to supplement it.  To get Build you'll have to find its private implementation in C/C++ or provide the information from Java via JNI.

**Pseudo Code:**

```
android_main(struct *android_app){
    JNIEnv *env = android_app->activity->env;
    jclass build_class = FindClass(env, "android.os.Build");
    jfieldID brand_id = GetStaticFieldID(env, build_class, "BRAND", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring brand_obj = (jstring)GetStaticObjectField(env, brand_id);
}
```

Comment: thank-you. I am unable to find its C/C++ implementation, however I can try and retrieve this info from Java via JNI. I see examples for this where 'JNIEnv*` is a function paramater, later used to call methods such as `GetMethodID` and `CallVoidMethod`, however I'm not sure where or how in my native method I could call this from? Where would I get this JNIEnv* parameter from?

Comment: (ie my purely native app has 'android_main` as my entry point into my purely native app, hence i'm not sure how to call a function that takes JNIEnv* as a parameter)

Comment: Ahh, this is going to be a problem, what kind of information are you looking for from Build?

Comment: Basically I need the device information, such as Build.MODEL, Build.BRAND, Build.DEVICE and Build.VERSION.RELEASE

Comment: Are you using "android_native_app_glue.h" or just "native_activity.h" to make your app? From there I can give you some pseudo code.

Comment: Thank-you - I am using android_native_app_glue (similar to the Native-Activity sample found in the NDK). User inputs must be detected natively for my app, which is why this sample worked well for me and why I need android_main.

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried it but unfortunately crashes at `jclass build_class = env->FindClass("android.os.Build");`

I'm calling this from 'android_main`.

Comment: Its only a rough sketch of what the code will look like. I hope it helped.

Comment: Yes, it's not "android.os.Build" but "android/os/Build", although the first also works on some devices and Android versions.

Answer (score 22):

These values are easy to obtain in native code via the interface defined in `<sys/system_properties.h>`, which has been around since the first NDK release. You just need to know the string identifier used on the Java side. Fortunately, with an open-source OS, we can find these easily. Here is a working example of retrieving the model name.

```
#include <sys/system_properties.h>

//
// Public codes are defined in http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String).
// Codes below are defined in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Build.java.
// Items with * are intended for display to the end user.
//

#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_VERSION_RELEASE     "ro.build.version.release"          // * The user-visible version string. E.g., "1.0" or "3.4b5".
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_VERSION_INCREMENTAL "ro.build.version.incremental"      // The internal value used by the underlying source control to represent this build.
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_VERSION_CODENAME    "ro.build.version.codename"         // The current development codename, or the string "REL" if this is a release build.
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_VERSION_SDK         "ro.build.version.sdk"              // The user-visible SDK version of the framework.

#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_MODEL               "ro.product.model"                  // * The end-user-visible name for the end product..
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_MANUFACTURER        "ro.product.manufacturer"           // The manufacturer of the product/hardware.
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_BOARD               "ro.product.board"                  // The name of the underlying board, like "goldfish".
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_BRAND               "ro.product.brand"                  // The brand (e.g., carrier) the software is customized for, if any.
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_DEVICE              "ro.product.device"                 // The name of the industrial design.
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_PRODUCT             "ro.product.name"                   // The name of the overall product.
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_HARDWARE            "ro.hardware"                       // The name of the hardware (from the kernel command line or /proc).
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_CPU_ABI             "ro.product.cpu.abi"                // The name of the instruction set (CPU type + ABI convention) of native code.
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_CPU_ABI2            "ro.product.cpu.abi2"               // The name of the second instruction set (CPU type + ABI convention) of native code.

#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_DISPLAY             "ro.build.display.id"               // * A build ID string meant for displaying to the user.
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_HOST                "ro.build.host"
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_USER                "ro.build.user"
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_ID                  "ro.build.id"                       // Either a changelist number, or a label like "M4-rc20".
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_TYPE                "ro.build.type"                     // The type of build, like "user" or "eng".
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_TAGS                "ro.build.tags"                     // Comma-separated tags describing the build, like "unsigned,debug".

#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_FINGERPRINT         "ro.build.fingerprint"              // A string that uniquely identifies this build. 'BRAND/PRODUCT/DEVICE:RELEASE/ID/VERSION.INCREMENTAL:TYPE/TAGS'.


char model_id[PROP_VALUE_MAX]; // PROP_VALUE_MAX from <sys/system_properties.h>.
int len;
len = __system_property_get(ANDROID_OS_BUILD_MODEL, model_id); // On return, len will equal (int)strlen(model_id).
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the information which was missing and which is not obvious or visible anywhere in the public android ndk documentation. Here is a link to the sources if you're interested in the method signatures and contracts: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/android-1.6_r1/libc/include/sys/system_properties.h

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this unfortunately. You could always start in VM and jump down via JNI to native after retrieving the values you want to access.